# OrientDB Spatial Module Distance Calculation

Tags: sql, orientdb, spatial

I need to calculate distance of two positions on OrientDB with new Spatial Module which is available for version 2.2. I have checked documentation (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Module.html) but couldn't find anything. I can calculate distance on my own but that time, what is the point to use the Spatial Module if I will not use spatial capabilities?

Also I need to check that if two positions are less than a threshold value. Again I don't have any documentation given by OrientDB.

Here are the two Java method signatures that I'm trying to implement.

```
double distance(Vertex gateway, Vertex sink);

boolean isInDistance(Vertex from, Vertex to, double distanceX, double distanceY);
```

Actually out of already implemented SQL-MM functions, ST_DISTANCE is needed to be implemented. I need a solution as a ST_DISTANCE replacement, I guess.

Thank you for your help.